# Is the boundary of a rooted tree with finite valence compact?

Tags: logic, topological-groups, trees

Given an infinite rooted tree $T$ with root $v$ it is possible do define the boundary $\partial T$ of $T$ to be the set of ininite paths emanating from $v$. If $T$ has bounded valence, then the natural tooplogy on $\partial T$ makes it compact.

I know that $\partial T$ is no longer compact if $T$ has vertices of infinite valence, but I am not sure what is the case when the vertices of $T$ all have finite valence, but such that the valences are globally unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the valences are finite, the boundary is still compact, even if the valences aren't bounded. Proof: For each natural number $n$, let $D_n$ be the set of vertices at distance $n$ from the root $v$. Because all the valences are finite, each of these sets $D_n$ is finite. So each $D_n$, when equipped with the discrete topology, is a compact space. Therefore so is the product $\prod_nD_n$. The boundary of your tree is a closed subset of this product, so it's also compact.

Comment: I see, its a quick consequence of Tychonoff's Theorem. Thank you I wasn't sure if bounded valence mattered.